# Is there a way to Ignore tests at runtime based on config property

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a bunch of selenium test classes and I am trying to Ignore some tests without making any code changes. There are properties in appsettings with bool true/false values to determine if the TestMethods within a class should be run or ignored. I don't want to add Ignore attribute as Ignore attribute means I have to update the attribute for each TestClass that needs to be updated.

I searched but I am always ending up with Ignore attribute on the TestClass or TestMethods but nothing to skip at runtime based on a condition.

Comment: Create  a master test, that only calls other tests when condition is right.  Then only execute the master test at run time.

Comment: This may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182460(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Add categories to your test and run mstest only based on those categories